# WPF parent of submenus not aligning correctly in WinXP

Tags: wpf, menu, windows-xp, alignment

When I make `MenuItem` in WPF that has a list of `MenuItem`s nested inside it throws the alignment off of the parent. But this is only in Windows XP, everything works fine in Windows 7. I think it is because it draws and arrow on the right hand side which throws the alignment off for some reason.

What it looks like:

[image]

What it needs to look like but with the arrow and everything:

[image]

Comment: I noticed the same thing on Win 7 so it doesn't appear to be OS specific...